# Can ping the website with domain name but can't browse them , why?

Tags: networking, vpn, browser

Some websites like `twitter and facebook and youtube` are blocked in my country so I need to use VPN so I can access to them , and I didn't have any problem with them until today

The problem is I can ping all these websites that I mentioned (with vpn on) but I can't browse them with `chrome or firefox`
I set my DNS with the `resolveconf/head` file and also I can connect with telnet to any of them `telnet twitter.com 80` so I can make a TCP connection to them 
The only change I made today was about wifi driver and as far as I know it doesn't have any effect on this (if it has tell me )

Is there any settings that I haven't looked at yet ?!

PS: All websites that aren't blocked work well, only have problem with blocked websites that shouldn't be blocked anymore when I'm using VPN ( I can ping them by their domain name but can't brows them with Browsers , that't really interesting !! )

```
default dev ppp0 proto static scope link metric 50 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp2s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
10.10.0.0 dev ppp0 proto kernel scope link src 10.10.16.225 metric 50 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp2s0 scope link metric 1000 
185.180.15.243 via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp2s0 src 192.168.1.120 
185.180.15.243 via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp2s0 proto static metric 600 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.120 metric 600 
192.168.1.1 dev wlp2s0 proto static scope link metric 600 
192.168.61.0/24 dev vmnet1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.61.1 
192.168.223.0/24 dev vmnet8 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.223.1
```

Comment: It sounds like your connection is not being routed over your VPN. Could you run `sudo route` and add the output here.

Comment: I don't know what's happening here ! now I can ping and browse some sites like twitter but I can't do the same for facebook or youtube.com , today's morning all works well , last night nothing work correctly , I hope you can help me dud , here it is ip route output command ( I edit the Post) @RyanJ.Yoder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've searched many topics for this problem and I finally resolve the problem , the problem was the size of MTU packets of my Wlan card 
I reduce it to 1200 ( previous size was 1500 ) with `sudo ifconfig wlp2s0 mtu 1200`
 command ( wlp2s0 is my wireless card) and the problem was solved